# Does an existing unprotected conductor need to be immediately rewired?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, grounding

While cleaning up under the sink, I noticed that an existing owner wired the disposal outlet as shown:

[image: t]

It has a red conductor traveling into the crawlspace without a plastic or metallic sheath.

I will use a tester to determine if this wire is the red load from the breaker as its supposed to indicate, or whether the retrofit added this as a grounding wire.

Regardless my suspicion is that this should be redone as soon as possible to prevent fire?

Comment: Can you take the faceplate off an determine where the red wire is attached? If it's attached the ground, this would be OK. If it's attached to anything else... not so much.

Comment: Do you think the wire comes _out_ of this box and goes on to power something else, or does it come from the main panel to power this outlet (or half of this outlet)?  I guess it could also come from a switch?

Comment: What is the cord that's plugged into the outlet for??

Comment: Can you get into the crawl space?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will open the box and see where the wire is connected. The thing connected to it is the garbage disposal in sink.

Comment: Can you turn off the power to that box, open it up, and post photos of the inside please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is this is a retrofit ground wire, added to upgrade a two-prong receptacle to a three-prong.  If this is the case, the wire would go from the ground terminal on that receptacle to another ground - the code allows several things for the other ground.  It should not be orange, instead green or bare, and it should be installed in a more "neat and workmanlike" manner, but if it does ground the receptacle, it's a good thing.

If it's not, it's pretty weird, a code violation, and a hazard that I'd give prompt attention.

To determine what it is, you'd need to kill power and look at what's going on inside that box, and determine where the other end of that wire goes.

Comment: If it is a ground, re-do it better with green wire if that's not too difficult, but at the very least maybe get some green tape and mark the wire in multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

I bet is ground. Buy green elektical tape and you are done and even fine with the code.(in CA). Cheap and fast. If not, you should rewire the complete outlet. But I almost would bet it is ground.